Are there any stats, or way the community can obtain details on how Discussions are performing?
It's not a secret that, at least from users active on Meta, that Discussions as a feature has not been well received. Every time I visit the feature I feel like I end up flagging almost every post on the first 2 pages as "Not suitable for discussions" (as they're just a bad question that although on-topic on main, would likely be closed due to being unclear or lacking details) or spam.
Unlike posts on the main site, however, Discussions do not appear in Moderator Tools, nor are they exposed over on SEDE. Not to mention that flags don't appear in a user's history and 10k+ users can't see deleted posts even with a link.
There's therefore no real obvious basis for us, as users, to see the volume of content that is both good and bad (which due to a lack of downvote feature I would suggest a post with a score of <= 1 is bad, 2 is "neutral" (like a zero score post of main) and 3+ is good), or how much has been removed as off-topic. We also have no way of seeing how many of these posts had user engagement.
Is there anywhere that the community can see how the feature is doing, like we can with "normal" posts? If not, will Stack Overflow be providing any consistent and transparent stats on the feature to the community? If not, then surely there should be one (developed)? If Stack Overflow (the company) truly wants the feature to grow, then getting the community on board is going to be key.

It's not doing so great.

@chivracq Mods don't have access to their Discussions stats either.

In the lack of downvote button, I use the upvote to show my disapproval. These votes are meaningless anyway without the option to downvote.

Both Mods, I've seen your replies, but hum Discussion-Mods should still have some stats, about how many Posts (Replies) and complete Discussions they've deleted... And if those Stats (or History) are not provided "by the System", not complicated to (automate) keep(ing) track of that, even if a few ones get lost in the (aggregated) count...

This question seems to touch on both: how discussions are doing and why discussions seem to be doing badly? It seems very obvious that discussions are not doing great even without knowing the exact stats. Does this question want a discussion about why discussions aren't working or simply an official reply on the request for statistics?

I suppose the problem is that if the answer is "yes" there is a feature then it's not a [[meta-tag:feature-request]], @chivracq , where as if there isn't then I suppose it does become one. I took the route of "there must be something", but I can easily make this a [[meta-tag:support]] and [[meta-tag:feature-request]].

@ThomA, yep-yep, I understand, and oops feat-req is with a dash, not an underscore like I thought, re-oops..! Well, like I mentioned, I suppose the 'Discussions' Mods have more Info/Stats that they could maybe share,  => once a month or at any regular rate they may want/be allowed... // Also interested by your Answer/Reply to 'NoData...' about the real purpose of your Qt...

(feature-request) Make Discussions posts available in SEDE

Besides once in a while stats provided by CMs on the number of flags handled, Discussion-Mods don't have access to any stats. cc:@chivracq

At this point it's just to find out if the stats are available, and if not If they can be, @chivracq . Seeing what those stats suggest and if there's anything the community might consider worth while would be a separate matter; no point putting the cart before the horse.
